# melt columns and add 20 minutes to each row in date column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to take this dataframe(with 1 row in this example):

```
id    Date                    value_now    value+20min    value+60min    value+80min
0     2015-01-11 00:00:01        12             15            18             22
```

and to transform it to this:

```
id    Date                    Value
0     2015-01-11 00:00:01      12     
0     2015-01-11 00:20:01      15     
0     2015-01-11 00:40:01      18     
0     2015-01-11 01:00:01      22
```

as you can see I need to change the value in respond to the columns and create rows, I understood I can do it using melt, but I'm having hard time doing it.
Please help me with that.....
Thank you!

Comment: Need to add the timedelta @anky

Comment: @anky_91 it won't work using df.melt('id', 'Date')

Comment: but why is `2015-01-11 00:80:01 ` ? why not add the extra hour to the date?

Comment: @anky_91 you are correct, I fixed it, it was a mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can melt the dataframe then use the `variable` column and split on `+` then use the right side of the split and convert to timedelta and add them back to date:

```
final = df.melt(['id','Date'])
final['Date'] += pd.to_timedelta(final['variable'].str.split('+').str[1].fillna('0min'))
print(final.drop('variable',1))
```

---

```
   id                Date  value
0   0 2015-01-11 00:00:01     12
1   0 2015-01-11 00:20:01     15
2   0 2015-01-11 00:40:01     18
3   0 2015-01-11 01:20:01     22
```

Another way proposed by @YOBEN_S where you can find the numeric in the variable column and convert to timedelta and add with the Date with `df.assign`:

```
final1 = (df.melt(['id','Date']).assign(Date=lambda x : 
        x['Date']+pd.to_timedelta(x['variable'].str.findall(r'\d+')
        .str[0].fillna(0).astype(float),unit='min')))
```

Comment: Nice answer, pretty much a one liner!

Comment: @anky_91 what is m['variable'] ?

Comment: Huh `to_timedelta` parses `xmin`, of course, nice :) +1

Comment: You can add `df.melt(['id','Date']).assign(Date=lambda x : x['Date']+pd.to_timedelta(x['variable'].str.findall(r'\d+').str[0].fillna(0).astype(float),unit='min'))
`

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach:

```
out = df.melt(id_vars=['id', 'Date'])

minutes = pd.to_numeric(out.variable.str.rsplit('+',1).str[-1]
                                    .str.rstrip('min'), 
                        errors='coerce')

out['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(out.Date)

out['Date'] = out.Date + pd.to_timedelta(minutes.fillna(0), unit='m')
```

---

```
print(out.drop('variable',1))

id                Date               value
0  2015-01-11 2020-02-14 00:00:01     12
1  2015-01-11 2020-02-14 00:20:01     15
2  2015-01-11 2020-02-14 00:40:01     18
3  2015-01-11 2020-02-14 01:20:01     22
```